# print(f"...:")-statement too long - break it into multiple lines without messing up the format

Tags: string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a console program with formatted output. to always get the same length of the printout, I have a rather complex formatted print output.

```
print(f"\n{WHITE_BG}{64*'-'}")
print(f"\nDirektvergleich{9*' '}{RED}{players[0].name}{4*' '}{GREEN}vs.{4*' '}{RED}{players[1].name}{CLEAR}\n")
print(f"""{15*'~'}{' '}{YELLOW}Gesamt{CLEAR}:{' '}{players[0].name}{' '}{GREEN}{int(player1_direct_wins)}{(int(4-len(player1_direct_wins)))*' '}-{(int(4-len(player1_direct_losses)))*' '}{int(player1_direct_losses)}{CLEAR}{' '}{players[1].name}{' '}{(28-len(players[0].name)-len(players[1].name))*'~'}\n""")
print(f"""{15*'~'}{' '}{YELLOW}Trend{CLEAR}:{'  '}{players[0].name}{' '}{GREEN}{int(player1_trend_wins)}{(int(4-len(player1_trend_wins)))*' '}-{(int(4-len(player1_trend_losses)))*' '}{int(player1_trend_losses)}{CLEAR}{' '}{players[1].name}{' '}{(28-len(players[0].name)-len(players[1].name))*'~'}""")    
print(f"\n{WHITE_BG}{64*'-'}")
```

This leads to the following output in my windows cmd

[image]

For readibility purpose, I tried to make the print over multiple lines, therefore I found on stackoverflow the idea to start with triple quotes. But when I cut this print(f"...") statement in the middle, I mess up my formatting.

Example:

```
print(f"\n{WHITE_BG}{64*'-'}") #als String einspeisen?!
print(f"\nDirektvergleich{9*' '}{RED}{players[0].name}{4*' '}{GREEN}vs.{4*' '}{RED}{players[1].name}{CLEAR}\n")
print(f"""{15*'~'}{' '}{YELLOW}Gesamt{CLEAR}:{' '}{players[0].name}{' '}{GREEN}{int(player1_direct_wins)}{(int(4-len(player1_direct_wins)))*' '}-
    {(int(4-len(player1_direct_losses)))*' '}{int(player1_direct_losses)}{CLEAR}{' '}{players[1].name}{' '}{(28-len(players[0].name)-len(players[1].name))*'~'}\n""")
print(f"""{15*'~'}{' '}{YELLOW}Trend{CLEAR}:{'  '}{players[0].name}{' '}{GREEN}{int(player1_trend_wins)}{(int(4-len(player1_trend_wins)))*' '}-
    {(int(4-len(player1_trend_losses)))*' '}{int(player1_trend_losses)}{CLEAR}{' '}{players[1].name}{' '}{(28-len(players[0].name)-len(players[1].name))*'~'}""")       
print(f"\n{WHITE_BG}{64*'-'}")
```

leads to...

[image]

can anyone point me in the right direction how to format my output in the displayed way, but without having this absurd long line length.

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triple quoted strings preserve newline characters, so they are indeed not what you want here. Now when it finds two adjacent strings, the Python parser automagically concatenates them into a single string, i.e.:

```
s = "foo" "bar"
```

is equivalent to

```
s = "foobar"
```

And this works if you put your strings within parens:

```
s = ("foo" "bar")
```

in which case you can put each string on its own line as well:

```
s = (
    "foo"
    "bar"
    )
```

This also applies to "fstrings" so what you want is something like:

```
print((
    f"{15*'~'}{' '}{YELLOW}Gesamt{CLEAR}:{' '}{players[0].name}{' '}{GREEN} " 
    f"{int(player1_direct_wins)}{(int(4-len(player1_direct_wins)))*' '}-"
    f"{(int(4-len(player1_direct_losses)))*' '}{int(player1_direct_losses)}"
    f"{CLEAR}{' '}{players[1].name}{' '}{(28-len(players[0].name)-"
    f"len(players[1].name))*'~'}\n"
    ))
```

That being said, I'd rather use intermediate variables than trying to cram such complex expressions in a fstring.

Comment: thank you, this worked! if you talk about intermediate variables, would you mean putting something like
`f"{15*'~'}{' '}{YELLOW}Gesamt{CLEAR}:{' '}{players[0].name}{' '}{GREEN} "`
inside a variable and then just concat them in the final printout?

Comment: Nope, I mean doing all the computations like `int(4-len(player1_direct_wins))` outside the fstring (assigning the results to intermediate variables) so the fstring only contains references to variables and no complex expressions. This will make your code much more readable and maintainable (and possibly more testable too).

Comment: okay, got it. one thing more to do for this little program :-) thank you again!

Comment: And thanks @toby-speight for fixing my spelling mistakes.